# Prevent duplicate output for errors in Python logger

Tags: python, logging

I get duplicate logging output for exceptions and errors in my pythong `LOGGING` confirmation. It makes sense given the configuration:

```
LOGGING = {
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
        'sentry': {
            'level': 'WARNING',
            'class': 'raven.contrib.django.handlers.SentryHandler',
        },
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'verbose'
        },
    },
    'root': {
        'level': 'ERROR',   # Give me errors only
        'handlers': ['mail_admins', 'sentry', 'console'],
    },
    'apps.order_shipping': {
        # This module needs extra debugging, but now ERROR is duplicated
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
    },
}
```

how can I implement this in a better way?
I'd like to enable verbosity for some modules, without causing duplication of ERROR messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set [propagate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.Logger.propagate) to `False`:

```
{
# ...
    'apps.order_shipping': {
        # This module needs extra debugging, but now ERROR is duplicated
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
        'propagate': False,
    },
}
```

Comment: I'm curious, won't this block `ERROR` messages from being picked up by the root logger? So the only solution is duplicating the list of handlers for all other loggers too?

Comment: I've taken the non DRY route of repeating all handlers for all loggers. A shame, but I don't see any other way right now.